# Extra SOAP information in request

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm new to SOAP and maybe my question is a bit simple or weird.
In my app (spring-ws, JAXB) I have integration with third-party service for client background check using hr-xml standard. Full request looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <OrderBackgroundCheck>
         <OrderBackgroundCheckRequest>
            <Envelope version="01.00">
               <Sender>
                  <Id>DDF</Id>
                  <Credential>USERNAME</Credential>
               </Sender>
               <Recipient>
                  <Id>Some app</Id>
               </Recipient>
               <TransactInfo transactType="request" environment="alpha" mode="test">
                  <TransactId>1</TransactId>
                  <TimeStamp>2009-04-30T12:28:23</TimeStamp>
               </TransactInfo>
               <Packet>
                  <PacketInfo packetType="request">
                     <PacketId>1</PacketId>
                     <Action>OrderBackgroundCheck</Action>
                     <Manifest>BackgroundCheck.xsd</Manifest>
                  </PacketInfo>
                  <Payload>
                     <![CDATA[...]]>
                  </Payload>
               </Packet>
            </Envelope>
         </OrderBackgroundCheckRequest>
      </OrderBackgroundCheck>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Now I have a test code which sends a request:

```
BackgroundCheckType type = new BackgroundCheckType(); //classes generated by JAXB from xsd
// fill type with data
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(objectFactory.createBackgroundCheck(type));
```

`BackgroundCheckType` is root for the xml part inside `Payload` (goes in `CDATA`)
As far as I understand, spring-ws 'wraps' my data with SOAP `Envelope` and `Body`. I can create `OrderBackgroundCheck` and `OrderBackgroundCheckRequest` classes too and marshall it using JAXB.

But part inside second `Envelope` (with `Sender`, `Recipient`, `TransactInfo` and so on) looks related to some standard. Looks like which can be generated and maintained by some framework. And I don't know how and with what framework I can do that.

Maybe someone can help with that or just explain what is it? And why SOAP message contains two Envelopes at all?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all this extra stuff such as inner `Envelope` and `TransactInfo` is service-related. Third-party service requires this info exactly in this way. And no other options left expect support this manually.